# How to covert a GeoTIFF DEM to a standard raster format without losing quality or resolution

Tags: qgis, raster, convert, raster-conversion, data-quality

I'm working on a project, a spin-off of my graduate dissertation, to digitize LiDAR data of a portion of Tampa Bay (20x20 km^2 at 1:1 scale) into a Minecraft map. Ideally I want not just accurate heights but land cover, or else the map would be boring and hard to orient in. At first I tried using geo-mapgen, a program for a similar (some may say too similar) game, but it always gave Lua-related errors (which I am completely ignorant of) when I tried to load a map and I've given up unless the programmer can respond to my posts on its message board. Now I've been trying to use WorldPainter for Minecraft and I've had more success: I uploaded in the program a PNG height map converted from a DEM of the land I want to use and got it running in Minecraft but without land cover, so it's just 400 square kilometers of grass, some beaches, and the ocean. In WorldPainter, you can use a transparent layer of a land cover image, and while it can't automatically convert Minecraft land into biomes assigned to numerical values (which geo-mapgen can do), it can assist greatly in helping you manually sculpt biomes which is the program's specialty.

Here's why I'm asking here: I've used QGIS and data from the NOAA Data Access Viewer to convert the Lidar-derived DEM from GeoTIFF to PNG that was able to be read by WorldPainter, but I'm having more trouble converting a land cover image to a PNG or other format (JPEG, GIF, BMP) while preserving the sharp, cell-distinct quality of the land cover GeoTIFF. I can clip it to the extent of my Lidar DEM and lay it over spatially perfectly as a PNG in WorldPainter but it's too blurry after the conversion to help with making biomes. Can you convert TIFFs to a common format without compromising the quality? The DEM wasn't that big so I'm not concerned about file size. I actually used a free online converter for the lander cover TIFF to PNG as I'm not sure which tool to use in QGIS: neither Save as File nor gdal_translate seem to support the file types used by WorldPainter.

Comment: How are you exporting to PNG? That particular format has only limited bit depth, https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/png.html lists some common pixel types. You must be exporting from composer to colorize to 8-bit or 24-bit PNG which would explain the fuzzyness, try gdal_calc.py to scale the pixels from minimum to maximum, for example if the minimum is 0 and the maximum is 1200 this would be a scale of 0.1225 so your calc="A*0.1225" with -of PNG, this will not compromise the cell size or extent. BTW GeoTIFF could be argued as the most standard format (besides Esri ASCII) for compatibility.

Comment: It would help if I provided some metadata: https://imgur.com/a/MOQUMGA

Comment: I'm a noob at Python syntax, what's wrong with these commands? https://imgur.com/a/J9MRAV6

Comment: The problem is that you have tried to run the python script from your IDE, that's not a command window. Although GDAL_Calc is indeed a python script you execute it from a CMD window, if you have installed GDAL from GISInternals there is a shell batch, if you have installed from OSGeo4W there is an OSGeo shell, open whichever is appropriate and run your calc from there. If you want to do this a lot and/or keep a record of what you've done you can put the command into a windows batch file (text file, ext is .bat) then drag 'n drop from explorer into your shell and hit enter.